# Factoring out X(s) when solving a differential equation with Laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am trying to understand an example of solving a dif. equation with Laplace. I understand everything except when they add that $+ 1$ on the second line when they are factoring out $X(s)$.

The rearranging the equation obtained for $X(s)$, I got:

$$
\begin{split}
sX(s)+X(s)&=3\\
(s+1)X(s)&=3\\
X(s)=&\frac{3}{s+1}
\end{split}$$

Comment: This is simply basic factoring/algebra. $2x+x=(2+1)x=3x$. Surely you need some coffee ;P

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt
Thank you!

Comment: it's like that sometimes